# createjs newbie issue - changing score on event

Tags: createjs

I'm trying to decrease score of my hero on event. Specifically, when she misses her score decreases.

I've tried putting the event in the tick function and outside the tick function but both continue to decrement the score continuously.

```
function reducePower()
{
princessPower -= 1;
text.text = "Princess Power: " + princessPower;
gameStage.update();
}
```

Within the tick() function this code exists:

```
if(hitOrMiss == 'Miss')
{
reducePower();
//setTimeout(makeMada, 1);    
}
```

The gameStage.update here causes the score to reduce constantly, I just want it to take one off every time the condition is met i.e. once when she misses - as in onChange. I see there is a createjs onchange function but when I try to use it, it fails for me, I'm probably using it wrong. The code is large so not saved it all but I've created a JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3AJ48/

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this one myself. The score needed to be added outside the tick function as below for those who looked at the JSFiddle:

```
function onDeviceReady()
{
$("#image").rotate(
{ 
bind: 
    { 
    touchstart: function()
        {
        var rot = Math.floor ( Math.random() *24 ) *15;
        value += rot;
        $(this).rotate({ animateTo:value});
        if(value % 2 === 0)
            {
                setTimeout(reduceMonsterPower, 2500);
                setTimeout(hit,1000);
            }
        else
            {
                setTimeout(reducePower, 1500);
                setTimeout(miss,1000);
            }
        }
    } 
}); 
}

function reducePower()
{
princessPower = princessPower - 20;
}
function reduceMonsterPower()
{
monsterPower = monsterPower - 40;
}
```